# Linked List In a Class private C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm near to c++ and I am working on Linked List inside a class. I am trying  to pass an array of characters into a the linked list. Somehow when I print try to print it out. It comes out reverse. I trying to why is my code doing this but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
class foo{

public:
 foo(const char * s =""){
    head = Node::toList(s);
 }
 void print(ostream & in){
 for(ListNode *p = head; p!= nullptr;p=p->next)
    out << p->info;
 }

private:
struct Node{
 char info;
 Node *next;
 Node(char newInfo, Node *newNext):info(newNext),next(newNewxt){
 }
 static Node *toList(const char *s){
 Node *temp = nullptr;
 int x=0;
 for(;s[x] != '\0';x++){
     temp = new Node(s[x],temp); // Part where I do understand why I am getting reverse
 }
 return temp;
 }
Node *head;
}; 
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, foo src){
src.print(out);
return out;
};
```

Any tips or advice would be great.

Comment: decale the ostream operator as a friend. Inside the print you use out << but what you need is in << (you have declared the variable in) if that solved your problem tell me to provide it as an answer

Comment: 8 `{` and only 7 `}` Might want to fix that.

Comment: think what happens to the last letter in your input, that is what gets returned from to_list().thats what gets set to head. IN fact you have a LIFO list - aka stack. Just step through the code with a debugger

Comment: short version , step through the code with a debugger, watch what it does

Comment: Unless you are trying to write a linked-list as a learning exercise to understand link lists, you're better off using `std::vector` instead of a linked list.  Linked lists are not friendly to the data cache and `std::vector` is a debugged working component, leaving you free to focus on your application instead of writing low-level linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the list was initialized by a string using its direct order of characters then the function can look the following way

```
static Node * toList( const char *s )
{
    Node *head = nullptr;

    for ( Node **temp = &head; *s; ++s )
    {
        *temp = new Node( *s, nullptr );
        temp = &( *temp )->next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Take into account that your code fragment shown in the question won't compile.

Apart from syntactical errors you may not declare `operator <<` as a class member function for outputing objects of the class in a stream.